# AChartEngine source code and revision

Tags: achartengine

I'm looking for the source code of version 1.0.0 or 1.1.0. I found the SVN repo but only see the current development trunk.

Could you tell me to which revision correspond version 1.0.0 and 1.1.0?

So I could use svn checkout -r {revision}

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AChartEngine version 1.0.0 corresponds to revision 382.

AChartEngine version 1.1.0 corresponds to revision 534.